# Business rule check inside DAL service

Tags: c#

At now I have such code, creating or updating some entity by dto items.

```
public void Upsert(List<Object> items)
{
    var existings = _db.Get().Where().ToList();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var existing = existings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.SomeId);
        if (existing == null)
        {
            if (item.Property != 645)
            {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException();
            }

            // create new
        }
        else
        {
            // update existing
        }
    }
    _db.Save();
}
```

I want to move `if (item.Property` logic out of this layer. I cannot add some method to Object, it is simply dto. I also cannot subclass `UpsertService`.

What I can do is to pass `Action<Object> checkWhenNotFound` to `Upsert` method. Disadvantage - I need to write all those mocking `It.IsAny<Action<Object, NotOnlyObjectInReal, AndMaybeMore>>` in tests.

Other way is to inject checker inside `Upsert` caller ctor:

```
interface IUpsertService {
    void Upsert(List<Object> items);
    void SetChecker(Action<Object>);
}
public Owner(IUpsertService service)
{
    _service = service;
    service.SetChecker(CheckWhenNotFound)
}
private CheckWhenNotFound(Object item)
{
    if (item.Property != 645)
    {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

Is there commmon solution for such problem?

Comment: Do I get it right, the `IUpsertService` is your service that cannot be changed?

Comment: It is my service, but `IUpsertService` is only one of its interfaces, so subclassing is no way.

Comment: Can you change the service at all or is it sealed/locked/closed for any modifications?

Comment: I can change it, in my second snippet you see example of modification (added `SetChecker`)

Comment: Why offtpic? I think is is "fabricating a related realistic program that looks plausibly useful".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't add a comment, so I'm going to try to answer the question.

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you don't want the responsibility of validation to be in the `Upsert` method. If that is the case then you can invert the control to another class by passing a '`Validator`'. Which I think is what you are alluding to in the second part of the question but I would recommend the following implementation.

In a nutshell what you do is create a class which is responsible for validation which is injected into the main class. This makes this testable as well.

```
private readonly IValidator _validator;

public Constructor(IValidator validator)
{
  _validator = validator;
}

public void Upsert(List<Object> items)
{
    var existings = _db.Get().Where().ToList();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var existing = existings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.SomeId);
        if (existing == null)
        {
            _validator.ValidateEntity(existing);
        }
        else
        {
            // update existing
        }
    }
    _db.Save();
}
```

Example Implementation of the IValidator interface would be

```
public Validator : IValidator
{
  void ValidateEntity(object existing)
  {
    if (item.Property != 645)
    {
      throw new EntityNotFoundException();
    }
  }
}
```

You could take this further and use generics and allow the Validator class to decide what the object is and what needs validating.

Comment: With composition you could even combine multiple validators into one and do more the one validation at a time.